# Exporting collapsible table to HTML

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to export a jupyter notebook containing collapsible tables to HTML.
It is possible to produce collapsible tables using accordions from ipywidgets. Yet, the latter disappear when exported to HTML.
Is there any way to either keep widgets exported to HTML using an offline solution, or build collapsible tables compatible to HTML export ?

My code :

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame(({"A" : range(0,10),
                    "B" : range(10,20)
                   }))

# Accordion
out = widgets.Output()
with out:
    display(df)

accordion=widgets.Accordion(children=[out], selected_index=None)
accordion.set_title(0, "Accordion")
accordion
```